# How to call BGSAVE from BookSleeve?

Tags: redis, booksleeve

Anyone can tell me how to call command BGSAVE from BookSleeve to Redis?

I search a lot in BookSleeve available methods but not found any commands relative to SAVE or BGSAVE.

Thanks!

Comment: This now exists in 1.3.40, under `.Server`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would seem that I never got around to adding that; I don't think `SHUTDOWN` is there either. In both cases, I expect they *simply weren't things that are commonly performed at the reqest if a client* - but are usually either automated (persistence configuration), or instigated at the command line (manually or as part of a script) as part of routine maintenance operations.

I can get it added for the next build (probably with the "connection has admin commands enabled" check).

A *truly hacky* workaround for now (untested) would be:

```
.Scripting.Eval(0, "return redis.call('bgsave')", null, null);
```

(caveat: the above makes me shudder)

But again: if your application is just performing routine work, I would *probably* recommend using automatic redis persistence settings. If your application is a monitoring / maintenance front end, then `SAVE` doesn't seem too inappropriate.

> but not found any commands relative to SAVE or BGSAVE.

Actually, I would strongly advise avoiding `SAVE` on a production server, unless you know it is safely off to one side and not being used; `BGSAVE` is not so invasive.

Comment: I'm trying your `Eval` hack for SHUTDOWN now but it would be nice to have that in the API as well. I filed [Issue 55 on Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/booksleeve/issues/detail?id=55) to request it.

Comment: @jtb noted; I have to say it isn't something that most people use very often, but by that token neither is `FlushAll`, so if *that* is on the API, I can't think of a good reason not to have shutdown