# What is the StackExchange.Redis method name equivalent for Redis's BGSAVE command

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Is there an equivalent command for BGSAVE in the Stackexchange client ? 
If there is not then how do i go about to achieve the same thing ?

Comment: i'll use snapshotting instead.

Comment: It appears that the author "never got around" to adding it in the previous incarnation of the StackExchange.Redis client - perhaps the same applies today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804356/how-to-call-bgsave-from-booksleeve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can do it with:

```
ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("host").GetServer("host").Save(SaveType.BackgroundSave);
```